# BULK INSERT Completes with 0 Rows Affected. SSMS v18.2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to insert some data from a .CSV (Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File) with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Monthly --only Source and TotalView needed
    (
        [Row] INT --dropping after insert
        , [Type] NVARCHAR(8) --dropping after insert
        , [Status] INT --dropping after insert
        , [Source] NVARCHAR(255)
        , [TotalView] DECIMAL(10,3)
    )
;

BULK INSERT #Monthly
FROM '\\SERVER\Data\October_2019.csv'
WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
        , ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
        , FIRSTROW = 2
    )
;
```

But the query doesn't insert any rows, and doesn't return any errors (it was before when I was using a row terminator of \n). Sample of the first 5 rows of the CSV. Took a look in Notepad++ and they are CR LF.

```
" Row"," Type"," Status"," Source"," TotalView"
" 1"," [M]"," 0"," Website1"," 8885.305"
" 2"," [E]"," 1"," Website2"," 1499.709"
" 3"," [C]"," 0"," Website3"," 685.805"
" 4"," [E]"," 1"," Website4"," 593.347"
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: Also, the data sets has about 500 rows like this, but then has some more random text at the bottom (which I wouldn't want inserted). It's just 1 blank row between the bottom of the data I want, and this random text. Not sure how to filter that out, or if that could be causing this issue. I could do lastrow = n, but this wouldn't be dynamic going forward.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using (not what version of SSMS, which is meaningless here). You don't use the `FIELDQUOTE` parameter in your `BULK INSERT` statement, which leads me to believe you aren't using 2017+. As a result you won't be able to load this file with `BULK INSERT` as `" 1"` is not a number, and will generate an error. `BULK INSERT` did not supported quoted values prior to SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Could the leading spaces in the CSV column names be contributing?

Comment: The names of the columns will be seen as `" Row"` anyway, @AlwaysLearning, due to the lack of the `FIELDQUOTE` parameter.

Comment: @Lamu 15.0.18142.0. And switch Status to a varchar, then?

Comment: La`rn`u @joru100... And there is no SQL Server 15.0.18142.0. The latest version of version 15 (SQL Server 2019 Preview) is 15.0.1900.25. Use `PRINT @@VERSION;`, don't tell us the build version of your SSMS; it has nothing to do with the version of SQL Server you have.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a' and for whatever reason it worked, but with everything in double quotes. Will string those out.